# Parametric set of function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, parametric

Can someone explain me how we define the parametric set of functions because I have been confused.

For example if we have the parametric set of linear functions  $f_{\theta}: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb R$.

That is for a given $x\in \mathbb R^2$,  $f_\theta(x) =  \theta_0 + \theta_1x_1  + \theta_2x_2$ right?

If we want to define the parametric set of the quadratic functions $f_\theta: \mathbb R \rightarrow  \mathbb R$, How we will calculate it?

I want to learn from which term $f_\theta: \mathbb R \rightarrow  \mathbb R$, I will learn how many parameters $x_i$ I will have which linear which quadratic etc. Basically can someone explain me how this terminology works.